# Not able to deploy in deployed .war seeing myproject.war.undeployed

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss, wildfly

I'm new in development with JavaEE. I have code from my friend - a Maven Project. When I try to build it in maven and deploy by maven deploy plugin (writing "wildfly:deploy") I have got an exception during deployment of the war.

I have  received following exception in server.log:

> WFLYCTL0186:
>      Services which failed to start:
>         service jboss.deployment.unit."com.nada.jar".POST_MODULE 
>         service jboss.deployment.subunit."coivoiturage-ear.ear"."coivoiturage-web.war".INSTALL
>
> 21:10:05,410 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]
>         (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found coivoiturage-ear.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called coivoiturage-ear.ear.dodeploy
>
> 21:10:05,411 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found com.nada.jar in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called com.nada.jar.dodeploy
>
> 21:10:05,411 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found FabricaEAR.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called FabricaEAR.ear.dodeploy

My pom.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>pfa.covoit</groupId>
    <artifactId>coivoiturage</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>coivoiturage-ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pfa.covoit</groupId>
        <artifactId>coivoiturage-web</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pfa.covoit</groupId>
        <artifactId>coivoiturage-ejb</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.Alpha1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.ear.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>7</version>
                <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <filename>${project.artifactId}.ear</filename>
                <port>19990</port>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

i am not able deploy my war properly .I didnt see any reference to my war deployment in server.log or i didnt see any error also.
can someone help me please

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a deploy using the maven plugin, try doing it via management console and check if anything comes up in the log file.
At this point my best guess would be that a required jar or file needed for deployment may be missing , for which you will have to create module.
 If it gets deployed via admin console. I would recommend you to give the absolute path for the file and see it works.

> "Complete-Path-to-file"

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new of Wildfly, but I found a solution:

1. Stop standalone.bat by right Ctrl + C
2. Copy your_project.war to [Drive]:\wildfly[version of wildfly]\standalone\deployments
3. Create file your_project.war.dodeploy to [Drive]:\wildfly[version of wildfly]\standalone\deployments
4. Start standalone.bat Again (You may need to press enter button when you see your_project.war.deploying)

It seem like wildfly cannot create .war.dodeploy by its own.

I hope this will help new user of JBoss and Wildfly.